# How to add multiple different functions on single on submit command in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have one function for validation,and a second function for message output how I can run both of them together with a single submit click.

```js
var myform = document.forms.hform; // hform is name

myform.onsubmit = validation;

myform.onsubmit = exercise;
```

Comment: use myform.addEventListener instead

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap them to one function:

```js
myform.onsubmit = (e) => {
  validation(e);
  exercise(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call functions inside of functions…

```
function myFunc() {
   validation();
   exercise();
}

<button onsubmit=“myFunc”>
```

Comment: why are you using HTML onsubmit when the question does not?

Answer (score 0):

Modern javascript (by modern in this case I mean since about 2010 or even earlier) you'd use `addEventListener`

Like this

```
var myform = document.forms.hform;
myform.addEventListener('submit', validation);
myform.addEventListener('submit', exercise);
myform.addEventListener('submit', youSaidThreeFunctions);
```

You can add an event listener at any place in your code, so that's better than running the functions in another function

addEventListener is more flexible than using on*Event*

Answer (score 0):

```
let handleSubmit = (e)=>{
   e.preventDefault();  // prevents default functionality of browser of reloading the webpage
   validation();
   exercise();
   // you can add more lines of code / function to be executed when onsubmit
}
var myform = document.getElementById("respective id of the form tag");

myform.addEventListener('submit', handleSubmit);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
you can create two individual function where each fuction is called like a stack .

```
function validation(){
        alert(" exercise() function executed successfully!");
    }
     
    function exercise()(){
        alert(" exercise() function executed successfully!");
    }   
    <button type="button" onclick="sayHello();sayHi();">Click Me</button>
```

See how the code is functioning [Here](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=faq&file=javascript-call-more-than-one-function-in-one-click-event)

For more you can visit  and [Here](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-call-multiple-javascript-functions-in-a-single-onclick-event.php).